# IE11 растянуть блок flexbox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, layout

Добрый день. Имеется такая разметка

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
    }
    
.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.form {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <form class='form'>
      <textarea rows='10' cols='5'></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

В IE11 блок .content не растягивается по содержимому .form. Прошу совета, как можно исправить ошибку?
http://plnkr.co/edit/T834lQX6mtHtQ4zOWKfc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `flex: 1 0;` у формы и content заполнится.
А если нужно задать параметры `flex` используйте развёрнутую запись `flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis`.

ps проверил в вашем примере можно использовать и `flex` но только полную запись `flex: 1 0 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, указанному в вопросе здесь вообще не нужен флексбокс - ту же просто каскад элементов - один в одном. Нет нескольких, обернутых в флексбокс.

Ну а если оставить таки флекс, то этому одинокому селектору .content стоит разрешить тянуться как угодно:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
или
flex: 1 1 100%;
```